# Agrupar en un array informacion para luego generar select y consultas rapidas PHP

Tags: php, array

tengo un sistema que maneja varias sucursales y estas estan almacenadas en una base de datos, cada vez que quiero generar un select o mostrar el nombre de una sucursal tengo que hacer una consulta a la base de datos (inner join y demas).
Lo que deseo es almacenar esta informacion en un array para luego poder generar un select y tambien obtener la informacion directamente, esto lo hago ya que las sucursales son "estaticas" es decir el cliente no puede modificarlas solo yo que configuro su sistema.

Yo tengo esto:

```
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id_sucursal" => "1","nombre" => "Tahuantinsuyo","direccion" => "tahuantinsuyo 369","estado" => "1","default"=>true),
    "2" => array("id_sucursal" => "2","nombre" => "Jerusalen","direccion" => "Jerusalen 1169","estado" => "1","default"=>false),
    "3" => array("id_sucursal" => "3","nombre" => "Jose marti","direccion" => "Jose marti 569","estado" => "1","default"=>false)  
);
```

Lo que busco es:

1. una funcion que me recorra ese array y me genere un `<select>` como este: nombre.
2. Obtener la entrada del array en donde el valor de default sea true, esto lo necesito para que cuando no exista una id_sucursal el sistema ponga por defecto el que tenga `default = true`

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solucion y se las comparto:

```
<?php
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id" => "1","nombre" => "Tahuantinsuyo","direccion" => "tahuantinsuyo 369"),
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Jerusalen","direccion" => "Jerusalen 1169"),
  "3" => array("id" => "3","nombre" => "Jose marti","direccion" => "Jose marti 569")
);

echo $sucursales[1]["nombre"]; // OBTENEMOS INFORMACION DE ARRAY

echo "<hr>";

echo current($sucursales)["id"]; // OBTENEMOS LA PRIMERA ENTRADA DEL ARRAY
echo "<hr>";

$mOptions = "";
foreach ($sucursales as $k=>$v){
            $mOptions.="<option value=\"$k\">".$v["nombre"]."</option>\n";
        }

        echo "<textarea style='width:100vw;height:100vh'>".$mOptions."</textarea>";

?>
```